# Localization Text in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am having issues with localization text in SwiftUI. I created a file called "Localizable.string" which contains the following key and values.

```
"helloTitle" = "Hello!";
```

I use the localizedString as shown below:

```
var body: some View {
        Text("helloTitle")
            .padding()
    }
```

Instead of display "Hello" it displays "helloTitle".

Here are my build settings:

[image]

For some reason Base has 0 Files Localized. I am not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

Double check the target membership of your `Localizable.strings` file. It should be part of the same target as your view.

Comment: Yeah. It is part of the same target as the view since there is only one target.

Answer (score 0):

try renaming the file to `Localizable.strings`, note the "s"

Comment: Turns out it was a bug in Xcode previews. When I ran on the simulator, it worked fine .